# conectar con sql server con password cifrado

Tags: java, sql-server, jar

Solicito de su ayuda para solucionar un problema que tengo actualmente. Tengo un jar el cual debe realizar una conexión con SQL Server, la forma tradicional con el URL, user y password funciona de maravilla. Sin embargo me piden que este jar se conecte a la base de datos con una contraseña cifrada como la siguiente:

XXXXXX28f0b7d4803b32ce871f9541490b77202e7bc92a138aa43be3c63239770db1be178715c077345b1450dcXXXXXXX

A simple vista se pude observar que es un hash, pero he buscado por internet y no encuentro algo relacionado a generar una conexión JDBC con este hash con java

Alguien que pueda indicarme si es posible realizar esto y en su defecto darme el hilo para poder investigar y realizarlo

Saludos!!

Comment: [En este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) tienes alguna respuesta.